# How to using sed in pipelines

Tags: bash, sed

I have file, and I need replace one word in it.
I can find this word with many grep's and pipelines.

```
cat file | <many times grep here>
```

for example:

```
>> cat test.cpp | grep -o "\-\-window [0-9]* \"" | grep -o "[0-9]*" 
>> 71303214
```

How can i change result number in this pipeline?

Comment: pls give some lines in the file as example, also the goal you want to achieve. your "many times grep" is very likely not necessary and could be done in one shot.

Comment: #define CLICK(x,y) system("xdotool mousemove --window 71303214 " #x" "#y " click 1"); 

This is "target" line. Using "many times grep" is guarantee that I will not change the other lines

Answer (score 3):

You can use look-ahead and look-behind as follows:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\-\-window )\d*(?= \")' file
```

It looks for digits `(\d*)` in between a block of `--window_` and `_"` (`_` stands for space).

If you want to replace with sed, use:

```
sed 's/--window \([0-9]*\) \"/\1/g' file
```

It looks for `--window_digits_*` and replaces them with `digits` (`_` stands for space).

#### Update

If you want to replace it with another number, do:

```
sed 's/--window [0-9]* \"/new_number/g' file
```

Or you can even use a bash variable if you use double quotes (with single, it wouldn't expand the variable).

```
sed "s/--window [0-9]* \"/$new_number/g" file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello --window 234234 " a
hello --window 234234a " a
hello this is another thing


$ grep -Po '(?<=\-\-window )\d*(?= \")' a
234234

$ sed 's/--window \([0-9]*\) \"/\1/g' a
hello 234234 a
hello --window 234234a " a
hello this is another thing

$ sed 's/--window [0-9]* \"/XXX/g' a
hello XXX a
hello --window 234234a " a
hello this is another thing

$ number=22
$ sed "s/\(--window \)[0-9]*\( \"\)/\1$number\2/g" a
hello --window 22 " a
hello --window 234234a " a
hello this is another thing
```

Comment: This instruction remove change "--window 232323" to "232323"
It work but i need something like "--window 232323" to "--window 888999". Better when "888999" is bash variable. (I need to use double quotes in sed for it?)

Comment: Yes, which is what I understood you want. If not, inform please!

Comment: Ah now I see, instead of 234234 you want another number. For that, see my updated answer.

Comment: Change last comand to         
sed { "s/--window [0-9]* \"/--window $new_num/g" a }    and it be an answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure! I was about to update when you posted it. So now I think it works :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/--window [0-9]* \"/ {
   s/[^[:digit:]]//gp
   }' file
```

- sed with file as input (so no need of cat pipe before)
- use of -n for not printing output unless specific request (P in command)
- first pattern between `//` (regex reduced so you need to escape some meta char like \ / . *)
- (here) extraction of digit by removing other char of the line and print the result if it occur

As you see, grep is better in this case (more readeable and efficient)

Comment: If i understand right. Sed in pipelines is very complicated thing.

Comment: sed is not made in this optic but can often do it. The main interest is to avoid lost of performance due to pipe process but not to be readable. Use sed if a simple (efficient) tools does not do the job directly

Comment: @StepanLoginov wrt `Sed in pipelines is very complicated thing` - sed means "Stream EDitor". It was specifically created TO work in pipelines and so it isn't complicated to use sed in a pipeline in the slightest.

Comment: question was moire to recreate in 1 sed a serie of pipeline instruction not to use sed in pipeline itself

Answer (score 0):

I THINK all you're asking for is:

```
$ cat file
#define CLICK(x,y) system("xdotool mousemove --window 71303214 " #x" "#y " click 1");

$ var="888999"; sed "s/\(.*--window \)[^ ]*/\1$var/" file
#define CLICK(x,y) system("xdotool mousemove --window 888999 " #x" "#y " click 1");
```

If that's not it, update your question to show some representative sample input and expected output.